# JSFTP: ftp.ls doesn't work

Tags: node.js, ftp, sails.js

Im using node jsftp module and sailsjs. I am having problem with the ftp session, i think that's the problem. Correct me if Im wrong. I just need to display the file list when the user login.

Here's the problem. 
After logging in, the user is redirected to the homepage. However, after redirection the **ftp** instance is gone. Do i need to reconnect "ftp.auth" everytime i redirect?

Please see the code below. Thanks in advance!

```
/*---------------------
    :: Ftp 
    -> controller
---------------------*/
var Ftp = require('jsftp');


var dumpLog =  function (event){
        console.log('Code: '+ event.code);
        console.log('Message: '+ event.text);
}

var ftp;


var FtpConnect = function(){

    console.log('ftpconnect');
    ftp = new Ftp({
        host: req.session.user,
        port: req.session.user // Defaults to 21
    });

    ftp.auth( req.session.user , req.session.user , function (err , auth_res){
        console.log('reconnecting....');
        if(err){
            dumpLog(err);
        }else{
            dumpLog(auth_res);
        }
    });
}

var FtpController = {

    index : function (req , res) {

        if(req.session.user == undefined )
        {
            res.view();
        }else{
            res.redirect('/serve_folder');
        }
    },

    login : function (req,res){
        res.view('ftp/login');
    },

    auth : function (req , res){

        console.log('this is /auth');

        var ftp = new Ftp({
            host: req.param('host'),
            port: req.param('port') // Defaults to 21
        });

        ftp.auth( req.param('user') , req.param('pass') , function (err , auth_res){

            if(err){
                dumpLog(err);
                res.redirect('/');
            }else{

                dumpLog(auth_res);

                if (auth_res.code == 230)
                { 
                    console.log('store session');
                    //store credentials to session for persistent connection
                    req.session.user = req.param('user');
                    req.session.pass = req.param('pass');
                    req.session.host = req.param('host');
                    req.session.port = req.param('port');

                    console.log('redirecting: /serve_folder');

                    ftp.ls('/',function (err,files){
                        console.log(files);
                    });

                    res.redirect('/serve_folder');
                }
            }
        });


    },

    serve_folder : function(req,res){

        console.log('this is /serve_folder');

        ftp.ls('/',function (err,files){
            console.log(files);
        });

        res.view('ftp/folder');
    },

};
module.exports = FtpController;
```